# Is there a continuous surjective map of $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

a) If $\mathbb{R}^{w}$ is given the product topology, determine whether or not there is a continuous surjective map of $\mathbb{R}$ onto the subspace $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$.

b) What happens to a) if $\mathbb{R}^w$ is given the uniform topology or the box topology ?

Where $\mathbb{R}^{w}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n $ with $X_n=\mathbb{R}$ and $R^{\infty}$ is a subset of $R^{w}$ consisting of all sequences that are "evantually zero", that is, all sequences $(x_1,x_2,...)$ such that $x_i \neq 0$ for only finitely many values of $i$.

I don't have any idea for this problem. Thanks everybody.

Comment: Is the notation $\Bbb R^w$ suppose to be $\Bbb R^\omega$?

Answer (score 3):

For (a) the answer is positive: $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is a continuous image of $\mathbb{R}$. First of all note that $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ can be written as

$$\mathbb{R}^\infty=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} I_n$$

where each $I_n$ has some nice properties: it is compact, connected, locally connected and second countable (so that Hahn-Mazurkiewicz Theorem applies) and $0\in I_n$ for all $n$. For example $I_n=[-n,n]^n\times\{0\}^\infty$.

Now there's a space filling curve $f_n:[0,1]\to I_n$ for each $n$ by the Hahn–Mazurkiewicz Theorem. We can tweak each $f_n$ so that $f_n(0)=f_n(1)=0$ since each $I_n$ is path connected.

Now define

$$f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^\infty$$
$$f(t)=f_n(t-n)\text{ if }t\in [n,n+1]$$

It's a simple glueing of all those curves. The problematic points of continuity are integers only. But these are guaranteed to be continuous by $f_n(0)=f_n(1)=0$ property. Obviously $f$ is surjective.

To finish the construction just compose $f$ with any continuous surjection $\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$, e.g. $x\mapsto x^2$.

---

As for (b) I think that the answer stays the same because even though uniform, product and box topologies are different on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ they coincide on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$. Right?

Comment: I don't understand that we can tweak each $f_n$ so that $f_n(0)=f_n(1)=0$. Can you explain more clearly. Thanks

Comment: @Noname Glue each $f_n$ with two path: one from $0$ to $f_n(0)$ and the other from $f_n(1)$ to $0$. Does this help?

Comment: Very nice answer. But please could you give more detailed proof why $f$ is continuous? We have to show that preimage of any open set in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is open in $[0,\infty)$, right. I have tried but no results :(

Comment: @ZFR I've simplified $f$ definition. Each $f_n(t-n)$ is continuous on $[n,n+1]$ as a composition of continuous functions. Now since each $[n,n+1]$ is closed and those intervals form a locally finite collection and $f_n$ agrees with $f_{n+1}$ at $x=n+1$ then [the glueing lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma) applies.

Comment: Dear freakish! Thanks a lot for your answer. So i have read that pastung lemma may not be true for infinitely many closed sets (i know such example) but if we add the condition of local finitiness then it is true, right? I have never seen this before. It is really nice!

Comment: @ZFR yes. Generally the pasting lemma does not work for arbitrary covers of closed subsets. But it does work for locally finite covers. The reason is that every topology is [coherent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_topology) with any locally finite cover of closed subsets. This is not hard to proof and I encourage you to do that. Alternatively this particular continuity case can be shown from sequential contuinuity as well (which is probably faster).

Comment: What I learned is that the uniform, product and box topologies that $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ inherits from $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ are all distinct. See https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-2/section-20-the-metric-topology/problem-8-solution/